# Access violation while freeing a form in another form's OnDestroy event

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7. I am getting access violation error while freeing the form.

1) Create new Application Delphi 7 (Unit1)

2) Add new form (Unit2)

3) For Unit1 uses clause add Unit2 and write below code

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, unit2, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  form2 : TForm2;
begin
  try
    form2 := TForm2.Create(Application);
    //form2.ShowModal;
  finally
    //FreeAndNil(form2);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Form2 <> nil then
    FreeAndNil(form2);
end;

end.
```

4) Run the Application and close Form1 -- Getting below error.

[image]

I don't want to free Form2 Object on OnClose or OnCloseQuery, Because i have some code on these events.I want to free Form2 object after OnClose or OnCloseQuery.

why i am getting error and how to fix this?

Comment: In the destroy event the variable `Form2`is unknown, where did you declare it ? where did you created it ? From the code you posted this should not even compile

Comment: `Form2`is probably declared in `unit2`and never created in this unit. Either remove the declaration of `Form2`from your formCreate here, or move it to the private section of this form and remove the declaration in `unit2`

Comment: it compiled because Form2 is declared in unit2. read my prior comment

Comment: Simply Remove declaration of Form2 from  TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

Comment: @BMS That would mean creating an instance of a global declared object. I am not sure but that could create other troubles when Form1 is created more than one time for example

Comment: @GuidoG My answer is what the question is !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you describe can be reproduced in Delphi 7, following your steps. The reason for the access violation is that `Form2` is autocreated in the `.dpr` file (and that makes the application the owner of the form), but you also attempt to control its lifetime by calling `FreeAndNil(Form2)` in the `OnDestroy` event of `Form1`. At the time you attempt to free the form, it is already freed by the application.

It is not really clear, why you attempt to free `Form2` when the application (presumably) is about to terminate (since the main form is being destroyed). As the application is the owner you can safely let the application take care of its duties.

You need to decide, who you want to be the owner of `Form2`.

1. If it's going to be you, you should remove `Form2` from the list of autocreated forms (see `Project - Options - Forms` and move `Form2` to `Available forms`).
2. If you want the application to be the owner, simply don't `Free` the form, use `hide` and `show` methods to control its visibility, if needed, but leave it to the application to destroy it according its design.

By the way, the code you have in `TForm1.FormCreate()` has nothing to do with the AV you have seen. That `Form2` is a separate instance, and if the intention is to show a splash form, it's ok, as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  form2 : TForm2;
begin
  form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    form2.ShowModal;
  finally
    form2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The form doesn't need an owner, therefore the `nil` in `Create`. Since the variable `form2` is local, there's absolutely no need to nil it.

Comment: I would give you an extra +1 for the last sentence, if I could. <g>

Comment: Yeah @Rudy, I know <g>

Comment: Yes this would be best practice I agree, but in the code of the OP it seems he did not want to do ShowModal and that he wanted to free the form when Form1 closes. In that case a local variable wont work.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that `Form2`will be declared in `unit2` and again in the FormCreate of this form. You are simply using the wrong one.

I suggest removing the declaration of `Form2`from unit2 and only use the one in this unit, and also move the declaration to the private section

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Form2: TForm2; // Declare the form here, not in unit2
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // no need to check if Form2 exists, it is created in the FormCreate and will thus always exist
  // unless there is code somewhere that we cant see that destroys it.
  // Also no need to set the variable to nil as mentioned in the Tom's answer
  Form2.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I have removed Form2 variable Declaration from Unit2 and Moved Form2 variable to Private section in Unit1. Still i am getting the same access violation error.

Comment: on what line exact does the access violation occurs ?

Comment: @DelphiLearner Obviously there's still something wrong in your code. How are we to know?

Comment: The code in my answer will not produce an access violation. So you still have other code that we cannot see that has a problem. Since we cannot see it, we cannot help you with that

Comment: Actually, your code (with additional removal of the `Form2` creation in the .dpr to make it compile) produces an AV: **Access violation at address 20736E61. Read of address 20736E61.** on the line of `FreeAndNil(Form2)`. @Jerry fyi too.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Oops you are correct, I edited my answer to fix the AV

Comment: @DelphiLearner I have edited my answer, it will not produce an access violation anymore.